# Use HTML5 for print design

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I am trying out html5 for print design purposes. I want to generate some canvas graphics, some typography with custom fonts and html/css. My aim is to get a properly sized and styled sheet (A4, A5) and then print pdf from using browser print capabilities or even generate pdf on the fly if possible. What I want to get in the end is something like what I could do in Illustrator/Photoshop/Indesign but obviously without these rich graphic editors' effects. Are there any JS/CSS libraries made specifically for creating print designs with HTML5? May be some articles on the web about it?

Comment: You mean you want to implement a paint program in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few suggestions.

You can use [Fabric.js](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/svg_rendering/) to implement SVG manipulation within the canvas. You can use the same library to export SVG which then can be printed out. By using this library you can rotate and scale vector based shapes, which is something you do in e.g. Illustrator.

You can also just experiment with using SVG natively in the browser ([read this](http://ajaxian.com/archives/the-state-of-svg-browser-support-using-flash-for-svg-in-internet-explorer)).

If you want to generate a PDF you will need a server-side solution.

Hope this helps.